# Vee Validate Custom Rules not working in Laravel. Uncaught (in promise) Error: No such validator 'xxx' exists

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vee-validate

I have set up a Laravel with VueJs as a SPA. Also I integrated Vee Validate to validate all my form inputs.
The default rules work as expected. However I don't seem to get my custom rules to work. I always get the error message:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: No such validator 'xxx' exists.

I followed this tutorial: https://medium.com/@rafaelogic/creating-a-custom-rule-in-vue-vee-validate-83777b9a5126

Here I have imported Vee Validate and the custom rules in my app.js file
[image: app.js]

Inside validators/index.js I have the following
[image: validators/index.js]

That is the custom "rule" - just for testing inside validators/rules/number_of_electrical_feeds.js.

[image: number_of_electrical_feeds.js]

And that is the component that tries to use the rule - inside js/components/LuminaireLine/Form.js
[image: Form.js]

What's the error I'm making?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should unify your imports, the `vee-validate` and `vee-validate/dist/vee-validate.full.esm` are two different dist files and thus each maintains their own rules and ecosystem.

You need to decide which version of vee-validate you want to use and only import everything from that dist

That includes `extend`, and the components and basically any vee-validate API you will import.

```js
import { ValidationProvider, ValidationObserver, extend } from 'vee-validate/dist/vee-validate.full.esm';
```

You can configure a webpack alias to make this easier for you.